# Codeigniter: redirecting while passing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Is there a way to ensure that only member will be able to access the member controller?

Currently, people would just have to enter mywebsite.com/member to enter even without them to logging in.

This my main controller code:

```
public function members(){
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('member');
        } else {
            redirect('main/restricted');
        }
    }
```

This my member controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Member extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("member");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
}
```

I hope this clarify my question

Comment: Since you are mentioning it... why not using the session?

Comment: public function members(){
  if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
   $this->load->view("site_header");
   $this->load->view("member");
   $this->load->view("site_nav");
   $this->load->view("site_footer");

Comment: This is currently my codes loading the views, but this is without redirecting it to the member controller, because when i am using a member controller others without the session will also be able to access the member controller without the session am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Paste the code in the question, so that other users can help you too. I'll check your code asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would recommend you to use flash data. Is will be stored within the session but is only available for the next page load.

Controller 1:

```
$data = "your data or array";
$this->session->set_flashdata('key',$data);
redirect('controller2/method');
```

Controller 2:

```
$data = $this->session->flashdata('key');
```

If you need to keep it available for another page load:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('key');
```

To Protect the member controller you can simply do something like that:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Member extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('main/restricted');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("member");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
}
```

You can then also use the flash data code above to pass a error message back to your public controller.

Comment: Hi Johnny I have edited the question and hope it will be more clear for you.

Comment: I think that the usage of flash data can work, but it is somehow weaker that using session as I suggested, because you have  explicitly to keep the data in every controller you could probably add  (otherwise you risk data loss) , while with sessions it is always available. Everything IMHO.

Comment: Flash data are meant to be used only to store messages to be displayed to the user after an action, like filling a form.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, to redirect to another controller you can use the method

```
redirect('/controller/method');
```

If you need to access a session variable you first have to set the data in the first controller

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
                        'new_var'       => 'data value',
                ));
```

And to retrieve from the other controller (Member)

```
$this->load->library('session');
$new_var  = $this->session->userdata('new_var');
```

Comment: Hi Masiorama I have edited the question and hope it will be more clear for you.